# Emacs: Make custom scrolling function follow mouse but not change keyboard focus

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have some custom scrolling functions in Emacs, which help me get around a bug where a single scroll event sends two `<mouse-4>` or `<mouse-5>` actions.  I have:

```
(setq scroll-down-this-time t)

(defun my-scroll-down-line ()
    (interactive "@")
    (if scroll-down-this-time
        (progn
          (scroll-down-line)
          (setq scroll-down-this-time nil))
      (setq scroll-down-this-time t)))

(setq scroll-up-this-time t)

(defun my-scroll-up-line ()
    (interactive "@")
    (if scroll-up-this-time
        (progn
          (scroll-up-line)
          (setq scroll-up-this-time nil))
      (setq scroll-up-this-time t)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") 'my-scroll-down-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") 'my-scroll-up-line)
```

This works perfectly, except that the `(interactive "@")` isn't exactly what I want.  This causes whatever buffer that is under the mouse to scroll and to gain the keyboard focus.  I want a way to make it scroll, but not steal the keyboard focus (like `(setq mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't)` does for the normal scrolling library).  How might I achieve this?

I am using the development version of Emacs, so don't be afraid to give me any new features.

Comment: Its already syntax-highlighted, no? I tried `lang-lisp` as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/165553 but it didn't seem to change anything to I did not save my changes.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Looks syntax-highlighted to me.

Comment: Yeah, apparently it doesn't syntax highlight in the edit preview, which is why I asked.  I'll remove the p.s.

Comment: It highlights "lazily", i.e. there is a few seconds of delay.

Comment: Now with your edit, we all look like crazy people.  ;)

Comment: Yes, but now I no longer look like a crazy person in the question.  Clearly that's more important :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not redefine `<mouse-4>` and `<mouse-5>`, but instead:

```
(mouse-wheel-mode 1)

(defvar alternating-scroll-down-next t)
(defvar alternating-scroll-up-next t)

(defun alternating-scroll-down-line (&optional arg)
  (when alternating-scroll-down-next
    (scroll-down-line (or arg 1)))
  (setq alternating-scroll-down-next (not alternating-scroll-down-next)))

(defun alternating-scroll-up-line (&optional arg)
  (when alternating-scroll-up-next
    (scroll-up-line (or arg 1)))
  (setq alternating-scroll-up-next (not alternating-scroll-up-next)))

(setq mwheel-scroll-up-function 'alternating-scroll-up-line)
(setq mwheel-scroll-down-function 'alternating-scroll-down-line)
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  There is another bug that I'm fixing, I guess.  Without my changes, or replacing them with this, I just get `<mouse-5> is undefined`.

Comment: I replaced it with a version that works for me. Just tested it. Of course, I'm testing on Emacs 24.1, not the development version.

Comment: Still gives me `<mouse-5> is undefined`.  If you are interested, my init file is at https://github.com/asmeurer/dotfiles (I haven't pushed the stuff from the OP yet). Also, I'm on Mac OS X with iTerm2 and I built emacs from git clone using `--without-x`.  If I could figure out how to make mouse reporting work, that would be awesome.  I've given up on it, though, and figured it would be easier to just define my own functions and set `<mouse-4>` and `<mouse-5>` to them.

Comment: I'll definitely be using your `alternating-scroll-down-line` instead of my `my-scroll-down-line` regardless, though.  In case you couldn't tell, I'm still very new to Lisp :)

Comment: By the way, perhaps you could tell me the difference between using `(interactive)` and `(&optional arg)`.  Every other difference from your code and mine I understand.

Comment: @asmeurer Since you are running through a terminal window, it sounds like you don't have `mouse-wheel-mode` enabled. These functions are designed to be called by `mwheel-scroll`, which has an `interactive` form, and also expects the functions to take an argument.

Comment: Hmm.  Is `mouse-wheel-mode` the actual name?  `M-x mouse-wheel-mode` gives nothing, as does `C-h f mouse-wheel-mode`.

Comment: I also can't find definitions for these `mwheel-scroll-up-function`s that I am supposedly overriding.

Comment: They come with Emacs 24 in `mwheel.el.gz`. I don't use the development version, nor do I have X disabled. `mwheel-scroll-up-function` is a variable that contains a symbol for a function, not a function itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14034/discussion-between-asmeurer-and-michael-hoffman)