# Emacs: disable beep when trying to move beyond the end of the document

Tags: emacs, scroll, beep

Is there a way to disable the beep in Emacs when trying to move the cursor beyond the beginning or end of a document?  I normally wouldn't mind, but the momentum scrolling on my trackpad makes it so that it beeps a dozen times whenever I scroll to the top or bottom of a document.

I'd rather not disable the bell for other things, if that's possible.

Comment: [disable-carbon-emacs-scroll-beep][1] ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324457/disable-carbon-emacs-scroll-beep

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works pretty well for me to disable the bell *just* when scrolling to limits (add the following to your .emacs or other init file) :

```
(defun my-bell-function ()
  (unless (memq this-command
        '(isearch-abort abort-recursive-edit exit-minibuffer
              keyboard-quit mwheel-scroll down up next-line previous-line
              backward-char forward-char))
    (ding)))
(setq ring-bell-function 'my-bell-function)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324457/disable-carbon-emacs-scroll-beep)

Comment: Nice. I actually am perfectly fine with also disabling it for those other things too.  I just added my custom scrolling functions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532149/emacs-make-custom-scrolling-function-follow-mouse-but-not-change-keyboard-focus to that list and it seems to work.

Answer (score 34):

Put

```
(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)
```

in your `.emacs`. This will disable the bell entirely, which might not be what you want.

Comment: This disables the bell entirely, which isn't quite what the question was asking, but happens to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!